# How to insert textbox between string( C# (Winform)?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, desktop-application

I have to insert textbox between the string.
Is there any way to dynamically create textbox and then inject textbox in between string in C# Winforms. Here the screenshot, That shows what I am trying to do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Pgx.png)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please spend a little time and few words to explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
chbInform.Text = chbInform.Text.Replace("#", "textBox");
```

Or I didn't understand ur question...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just replace the values # with some other strings, the better way would be to change your `chbInform.Text` to following string:

```
"We will start taking order from {0} to {1}, Sorry for the inconvenience."
```

This way, you will be able to set these placeholder values to any other values like so:

```
chbInform.Text = string.Format(chbInform.Text, "your_first_value", "your_second_value");
```